# Key-value database options

Tags: python, c, database, redis, key-value

I have looked at the key-value database [Redis](http://redis.io/) and am curious about alternatives that would offer the following:

1. Instead of starting an external database engine as a separate process, and then connecting to it, e.g. via the [C interface](https://github.com/antirez/hiredis#readme):

   `redisContext *c = redisConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);`

   Is there an alternative that gives the option of including the database code as a library, and loading the data as a file within-binary? For example, given the binary `myDbBinary` and the command:

   `$ myBinary --filter=filterOptions db.dat`

   The binary `myBinary` would not start a separate db process and connect to its port, but, instead, `myBinary` loads the keys (and hashes) from the file `db.dat` into memory (or similar VM arrangement) which it can then filter (with `filterOptions`, whatever they might be) and perform key/hash lookups.
2. C and Python interfaces to data and storage directives.
3. Hash support, by which I mean a key maintains a hash table as a value.

Does any software like this exist?

Comment: You could use any of the *dbm modules (including "anydbm") in the standard libraries.  You'll have to do your own file locking and contention handling.  But, that aside, it's an extremely simple option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Redis works as a process, not as a library. There is no way currently of doing so. You can use alternatives like [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/) (which is more redis-like).

Kyoto has hash tables support for C and Python.

Alternatively you can use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) but it's quite different than what you asked.

Comment: SQLite does have considerable built-in and implicit lock management.  So you could have multiple processes sharing a single SQLite data store (files) and still get reasonable ACID guarantees (even over NFS) without explicitly having to code up your own lock management and contention handling.  (Note the concurrency support will be pretty weak, limited to your platform's fnctl/flock performance; but it's still sane for low traffic situations and you can grow out of it towards PostgreSQL or MySQL, etc later).

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is an in-process database.  It's relational, but you could build your simple key-value store in it.  It's also included in the Python standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You might try out [littletable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/littletable/).  It is a schemaless in-memory "database" that blurs the line between tables and lists. littletable uses no schema, it infers query and join columns from the attributes of the objects added to a given Table. All queries and joins return the results as a new Table (instead of introducing an artificial ResultSet or QuerySet collection), making it possible to easily chain various queries, unions, joins, and filters. Fields can be easily indexed and retrieved by index key - if the index is a unique index, then the single matching object is returned or KeyError is raised; if the index is not unique, a new Table of the objects with the given key is returned (which may be empty).  Tables also support many list-ish attributes, such as iter and len, and can be used as a standard Python collection in for loops and generator expressions.

littletable includes a generic DataObject class, which is very similar to namedtuple. But objects of any type can be inserted into a littletable Table.

Here is a demo/example: http://littletable.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/littletable/trunk/littletable_demo.py?revision=32&content-type=text%2Fplain

Get the latest version from SVN: https://littletable.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/littletable

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pickleDB.

You can use it like that:

```
$ pip install pickledb

>>> import pickledb

>>> db = pickledb.load('test.db', False)

>>> db.set('key', 'value')

>>> db.get('key')
'value'

>>> db.dump()
True
```